# PHP "\n" new line is not working. Even PHP_EOL

Tags: php, escaping

I tried to print a new line like this. but it is not working. Then i tried to print it with `PHP_EOL` But no luck. Why is that. My PHP version is 5.6 with XAMPP. I'm running on Windows 8.1. here my code

```
 <?php
 echo "Add a new line \n Add a second new line";
?>
```

It display output as

> Add a new line Add a second new line

I want get to know why is not working

Comment: `<br />` <- HTML break line `'\n'` <- Source break line (Right click -> View source code)

Comment: No I want get to know why is not working

Comment: Who is the donkey who gave me a negative feedback? lol See how important topic is that

Comment: *Who is the donkey who gave me a negative feedback?* What is negative on my comment?

Comment: no man i mean my post. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\ntry:

```
<?php
 echo nl2br("Add a new line \n Add a second new line");
?>
```

Comment: No I want get to know why is not working

Comment: because html does't understand \n but if you execute it in terminal php file.php, it will work or if you open a file and write into it.

Comment: What should I do to make that working on HTML?

Comment: <br> is the solution

Comment: No i mean without <br>? Any header modification is there?

Comment: use nl2br, as I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code: issue with your page content type

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
 echo "Add a new line \n Add a second new line";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new line on webpage you should use 
Use PHP_EOL or \n,\r,\n\r when you are writing data in a file.
From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

```
// Outputs: This will not expand: \n a newline
echo 'This will not expand: \n a newline';

// Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
```